# Is possible to use array values resulted from `string.match()` as options for a ts type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, rollup

Hey,

I think it may be useful to start by providing all the packages:

```
    "@figma/plugin-typings": "^1.17.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^2.3.3",
    "rollup": "^2.32.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
```

I have a `.json` file which from which I want to extract certain information.

```
// file.json
{
   ...,
   {
      "name": "Copy Selection",
      "command": "copySelection"
    },
    {
      "name": "Paste In",
      "command": "pasteIn"
    },
    ...

}
```

I'm trying to get all the commands from the `file.json` and use them as type options:

```
import manifest from '../manifest.json';

const regex = /(?<="command":")(.*?)(?=")/g;

const matches = JSON.stringify(manifest).match(regex);
const commands = [...matches] as const;

export type PluginCommands = typeof commands[number];
// results
// PluginCommands = string

// expected
// PluginCommands = "copySelection" | "PasteIn" | ...

const meh = ['ala', 'bala', 'portcolaa'] as const;

type mehType = typeof meh[number];
// mehType = "ala" | "bala" | "portcolaa"
```

I want this because I want to get use of vscode intellisense and autocomplete, and ts warnings.

While writing this question, an idea stroke myself, to write a rollup plugin to get the matches into a file.

✅ My solution:

I used the `rollup-plugin-copy` to create a modified copy of the json file.

Then I'm using variable as source for my type.

Below is the code I used:

```
// rollup.config
     ...
     copy({
        targets: [{ src: './src/manifest.json', dest: './build' }],
        targets: [
          {
            src: './src/manifest.json',
            dest: './src/',
            rename: 'manifestCommands.ts',
            transform: (contents, filename) => {
              const content = contents.toString();

              const regex = /(?<="command": ")(.*?)(?=")/g;
              const matches = content.match(regex);

              const results = `export const manifestCommands = ${JSON.stringify(matches)} as const`;

              return results;
            },
          },
        ],
      })
      ...
```

```
// another_file.ts
// import manifestCommands variable

type PluginCommands = typeof manifestCommands[number];
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing a JSON file will give you it's structure as a type, but it won't ever give you anything more specific than a `string`, so this isn't possible. JSON imports just aren't typed that strongly.

Also, `match` will only ever return `string`s, so that's not possible either.

---

To pull this off you'd need to treat your object in that JSON like source code, and not data. Which means you make it a typescript file

```
// manifest.ts
const manifest = [
    {
        "name": "Copy Selection",
        "command": "copySelection"
    },
    {
        "name": "Paste In",
        "command": "pasteIn"
    },
] as const
```

Then you can simply do:

```
type PluginCommands = typeof manifest[number]['command']
// "copySelection" | "pasteIn"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQzASwGYFNowLwwNoCwAUDKTAN7FnUwBEYCc6tAXHQMIgAOAnjAMroANumBRk4WgBoqNUrVBxEYACas6oXoJFiJYWrNIBfGSTKUzc+o2ZtaABQTR0MAJL7Tc+YuVq7XJyh0dwNLGBNiAF0YJxhQSChiYigeLhd7IQBXAHNkME4lJBUIHBgUtJBUeCQ0TCg8MEy4ACN0ACdIvAByHyKuyKA)

---

But if your file *must* be JSON, then this isn't ever going to work.

Lastly, I wouldn't ever recommend regexing through a JSON string for anything. It's *always* going to better to parse that JSON string and then crawl through the resulting values.

Comment: Relevant request to allow importing JSON `as const` is at [ms/TS#32063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!  (I didn't even have time to try my idea )

Unfortunately, manifest.json is the source for the plugin, and is required. 

I'm planning to try using `rollup-plugin-copy` to make a copy of the manifest.json file and also convert it into a ts file, have desired format, and use that as source of truth.

I'm already cloning the manifest.json into the build folder (I'm lazy) to not have so many places where I need to adjust (everything is in src folder).

Anyway, I'll let you know if that works.